# TypeScript export and import Module name has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

When I try to run the application in the browser I get in the debug console window the following message:

```
Module name "Person" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

Of course if merge the content of the .ts files all is working perfectly.

I create the `Person.ts` file:

```
export interface IPerson {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

export class Person implements IPerson {
    private _middleName: string;
    public set middleName(value: string) {
        if (value.length <= 0)
            throw "Must supply person name";
        this._middleName = value;
    }
    public get middleName(): string {
        return this._middleName;
    }

    constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) { };
    Validate() {
        alert('test');
    }
}
```

and the `app.ts` file:

```
import {Person} from "./Person"

class Employee extends Person {
    Validate() {
        alert('new test inside Employee');
    }
}

let p1 = new Person("Shahar", "Eldad");
p1.Validate();
try {
    p1.middleName = "";
}
catch (err) {
    alert(err);
}

let p2 = new Employee("Shahar", "Eldad");
p2.Validate();

document.body.innerHTML = p1.firstName + " " + p2.lastName;
```

and last my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="windows-1255">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.min.js" data-main="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

and last my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "files": [
        "app.ts",
        "Person.ts"
    ]
}
```

I tried at first to transpile with target es5 and then I moved to es6 (and last moved to the tsconfig.json file)

**Update**

I did like @Louis and it seems to work - copied all files from my question and only edited tsconfig.json to hold amd and es5. I couldn`t see any difference between the before and after the copy. Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `"module": "commonjs"` when you want the output of the TypeScript compiler to be loaded by RequireJS, is definitely wrong. You should use `"module": "amd"`. (You may need to change change your target back to `es5` too.)

The error you get is because with `"module": "commonjs"`, the compiler will output code similar to this for your `import {Person} from "./Person"`:

```
var _Person = require("./Person");
var Person = _Person.Person;
```

The call to `require` will cause RequireJS to execute but that will fail because RequireJS does not support such code directly. The code above would work if it is in a `define` like this:

```
define(function (require) {
    var _Person = require("./Person");
    var Person = _Person.Person;

    // Rest of the module.
});
```

When you use `"module": "amd"`, the compiler produces code similar to this snippet and it works.

Comment: Now it is screaming about the define like this: 
Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports, Person_1)

Comment: What files to you see the browser trying to load when you look in the network tab in the debugger?

Comment: I see index.html, require.min.js, and app.js

Comment: You mentioned in your question having tried to combine files. Make sure you're not combining anything. `app.js` should be the output of compiling `app.ts` and `Person.js` should be the output of compiling `Person.ts` and the two `.js` files should remain separate and served separately by your server. (They can be combined, but only with software that knows how to do it.) There should be a request for `Person.js` in your network requests.

Comment: They are not combined, I get two transpiled files - one named app.js and one Person.js.
I`m pretty sure this is part of the problem - there is no Person.js in the network tab.

Comment: Oops... It appears that you also need to change you target back to `es5`.

Comment: I moved the target to es5 - same result - Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports, Person_1)

Comment: Well, I've copied all of the code in your question here, the `index.html`, and your `tsconfig.json`, edited it according to my answer, and I get no error. Your code loads and the alerts do come up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130616/discussion-between-shahar-eldad-and-louis).

Comment: Sorry I have to get back to other things.

Comment: I did like @Louis and it seems to work - copied all files from my question and only edited tsconfig.json to hold amd and es5. I couldn`t see any difference between the before and after the copy. Weird.